# Type inference on anonymous functions with enrich-my-library

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, type-inference, enrich-my-library

Say I have a method that turns a (function on two elements) into a (function on two sequences):

```
def seqed[T](f: (T,T) => T): (Seq[T], Seq[T]) => Seq[T] = (_,_).zipped map f
```

In words, the resulting function takes two sequences `xs` and `ys`, and creates a new sequence consisting of `(xs(0) f ys(0), xs(1) f ys(1), ...)`
So, for example, if `xss` is `Seq(Seq(1,2),Seq(3,4))` and `f` is `(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b`, we can invoke it thus:

```
xss reduceLeft seqed(f)         // Seq(4, 6)
```

or with an anonymous function:

```
xss reduceLeft seqed[Int](_+_)
```

This is pretty good; it would be nice to get rid of the `[Int]` type argument but I don't see how (any ideas?).

To make it feel a bit more like the `tupled` method, I also tried the enrich-my-library pattern:

```
class SeqFunction[T](f: (T,T) => T) {
  def seqed: (Seq[T], Seq[T]) => Seq[T] = (_,_).zipped map f
}
implicit def seqFunction[T](f: (T,T) => T) = new SeqFunction(f)
```

For a pre-defined function this works great, but it's ugly with anonymous ones

```
xss reduceLeft f.seqed
xss reduceLeft ((_:Int) + (_:Int)).seqed
```

Is there another way I can reformulate this so that the types are inferred, and I can use syntax something like:

```
// pseudocode
xss reduceLeft (_+_).seqed         // ... or failing that
xss reduceLeft (_+_).seqed[Int]
```

? Or am I asking too much of type inference?

Comment: [Here](http://screencasts.chariotsolutions.com/uncovering-the-unknown-principles-of-type-inference-) Daniel Spiewak made a presentation about type systems and type inference in `scala` and other static typed languages. Maybe that's not exactly on topic, but anyway, I found it extremely interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why a type annotation is required in

```
xss reduceLeft seqed[Int](_+_)
```

but not in

```
xs zip ys map Function.tupled(_+_)
```

is due to the difference in type requirements between `map` and `reduceLeft`.

```
def reduceLeft [B >: A] (f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B 
def map        [B]      (f: (A) ⇒ B): Seq[B]   // simple version!
```

`reduceLeft` expects `seqed` to return type `B` where `B >: Int`. It seems that therefore the precise type for `seqed` cannot be known, so we have to provide the annotation. More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364931/how-does-the-type-inferencer-work-on-reduceleft).

One way to overcome this is to re-implement `reduceLeft` without the lower bound.

```
implicit def withReduceL[T](xs: Seq[T]) = new {
  def reduceL(f: (T, T) => T) = xs reduceLeft f
}
```

Test:

```
scala> Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(2,2,2)) reduceL seqed(_+_)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

The problem now is that this now doesn't work on subtypes of `Seq` (e.g. `List`), with or without the `[Int]` parameter:

```
scala> Seq(List(1,2,3), List(2,2,2)) reduceL seqed(_+_)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
              Seq(List(1,2,3), List(2,2,2)) reduceL seqed(_+_)
                                                          ^
```

`reduceL` expects a function of type `(List[Int], List[Int]) => List[Int]`. Because `Function2` is defined as `Function2 [-T1, -T2, +R]`, `(Seq[Int], Seq[Int]) => Seq[Int]` is not a valid substitution.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it the way you want, but look at `Function.tupled`, which is a counter-part to `.tupled` that solves this very same problem.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) zip List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + _).tupled
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
              List(1, 2, 3) zip List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + _).tupled
                                                   ^
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
              List(1, 2, 3) zip List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + _).tupled
                                                       ^

scala> List(1, 2, 3) zip List(1, 2, 3) map Function.tupled(_ + _)
res7: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: The signature of `Function.tupled` is `def tupled[a1, a2, b](f: (a1, a2) => b): Tuple2[a1, a2] => b`. What I can't work out how it knows the parameter types in the above example, whereas my method requires the `[Int]` in `xss reduceLeft seqed[Int](_+_)`.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure you *are* asking too much. Type inference in Scala [goes from left to right](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html), so the type of `(_+_)` needs to be figured out first before even considering the `.sedeq` part. And there isn't enough information there.